# Print an array of pipe-delimited values as HTML list item tags

Tags: php, arrays, explode, text-extraction, delimited

Data comes from Wordpress metabox in a form of single long array.

The data that I insert in metabox looks like this:

```
Rhine Riesling1|0,75 l|9,50 &euro

Rhine Riesling2|0,75 l|9,50 &euro

Rhine Riesling3|0,75 l|9,50 &euro

Rhine Riesling4|0,75 l|9,50 &euro
```

Final output should look like this:

```
<ul class="listmenuitems" id="listingmenu_1">
    <li><p>Rhine Riesling1 <span>0,75 l</span></p> <span class="listmenuprice">9,50 &euro;</span></li>
    <li><p>Rhine Riesling2 <span>0,75 l</span></p> <span class="listmenuprice">9,50 &euro;</span></li>
    <li><p>Rhine Riesling3 <span>0,75 l</span></p> <span class="listmenuprice">9,50 &euro;</span></li>
    <li><p>Rhine Riesling4 <span>0,75 l</span></p> <span class="listmenuprice">9,50 &euro;</span></li>
</ul>
```

How would I cut the array values into pieces considering the separator `|` and then loop through it to create a correctly formatted `<li><p>`?

I'm reading about PHP's `explode()` at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PHP explode command.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Loop through your array, on each entry call: explode("|", $entry);
then you can print out what you want like so:

```
$input_arr[];
echo '<ul class="listmenuitems" id="listingmenu_1">';
for($i=0;i<sizeof($input_arr);$i++) {

    $e = explode("|",$input_arr[$i]);
    echo "<li><p>" . $e[0] . "<span>" . $e[1] . "</span></p> <span class=\"listmenuprice\">" . $e[2] . "</span></li>";

}
```

Note there is on error checking and it is assumed that you have a complete and well formed array input.

Updated to add foreach ;)
And if the foreach loop is your fancy...

```
$input_arr[];
echo '<ul class="listmenuitems" id="listingmenu_1">';
foreach($input_arr as $i) {

    $e = explode("|",$i);
    echo "<li><p>" . $e[0] . "<span>" . $e[1] . "</span></p> <span class=\"listmenuprice\">" . $e[2] . "</span></li>";

}
```

Comment: No reason in particular... I always forget the exact formatting of it (slightly different in each language) so I just went with the for loop this time...

Comment: There ya go!  foreach is in there too now! :P

Answer (score 3):

```
list($name,$content,$price) = explode("|",$line) 
printf('<li><p>%s<span>%s</span></p> <span class="listmenuprice">%s</span></li>',$name,$content,$price)
```

Comment: Actually, this needs the loop through the array to be the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `vprintf()` will allow you to cleanly declare the HTML template string and immediately consume the returned array from `explode()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZS3aD))

```
$array = [
    'Rhine Riesling1|0,75 l|9,50 &euro',
    'Rhine Riesling2|0,75 l|9,50 &euro',
    'Rhine Riesling3|0,75 l|9,50 &euro',
    'Rhine Riesling4|0,75 l|9,50 &euro',
];

echo '<ul class="listmenuitems" id="listingmenu_1">' . "\n";
    foreach ($array as $psv) { // pipe-separated values
        vprintf(
            "\t" . '<li><p>%s <span>%s</span></p> <span class="listmenuprice">%s;</span></li>' . "\n",
            explode('|', $psv)
        );
    }
echo '</ul>';
```

Output:

```
<ul class="listmenuitems" id="listingmenu_1">
    <li><p>Rhine Riesling1 <span>0,75 l</span></p> <span class="listmenuprice">9,50 &euro;</span></li>
    <li><p>Rhine Riesling2 <span>0,75 l</span></p> <span class="listmenuprice">9,50 &euro;</span></li>
    <li><p>Rhine Riesling3 <span>0,75 l</span></p> <span class="listmenuprice">9,50 &euro;</span></li>
    <li><p>Rhine Riesling4 <span>0,75 l</span></p> <span class="listmenuprice">9,50 &euro;</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose your array is

```
$metabox;
```

Then

```
echo '<ul class="listmenuitems" id="listingmenu_1">';
foreach($metabox as $val)
{
$petabox=explode("|",$val);
echo '<li><p>'.$petabox[0].'<span>'.$petabox[1].'</span></p> <span class="listmenuprice">'.$petabox[2].'</span></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: why is this down-voted? care explain? +1 from me as I don't understand the problem with this approach.

Comment: @Sandro Dzneladze I didn't downvote it, but looking at the original answer, it has `while($metabox[$i])` with `$i` always being equal to zero. It doesn't have an expression to evaluate. Anyone can post an answer with a mistake in it, that's why the "edit" function is my friend.

Comment: @codewaggle why are you giving explanation when you have not downvoted it .Go and try other answers and don't bother about it :-)

Comment: I explained because Sandro didn't understand what was wrong and asked about it. No one else had explained, so I did. I'm not trying to give you a hard time and made a point of noting that that I've made mistakes and that I'm glad the edit function exists.